# why I got parameter must be 2D array error when I used imread with grayscale image?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, parameters, 2d

I got an error in `feature.local_binary_pattern`

I used `imread(img_path, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` but it didn't fix it.

The images that I read is `grayScale`

THE FULL Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 76, in <module>
    lbp.append(feature.local_binary_pattern(img, 8, 3, method="default"))
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skimage/feature/texture.py", line 333, in local_binary_pattern
    check_nD(image, 2)
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skimage/_shared/utils.py", line 655, in check_nD
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: The parameter `image` must be a 2-dimensional array
```

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from skimage import feature #-> python -m pip install -U scikit-image
from PIL import  ImageOps

#load and labeling the data
#__________________________________________________________________________

DIRECTORY ="/Users/myname/Desktop/LSB"
FILES = ['cover', 'stego']
data = []

for file in FILES:
    path = os.path.join(DIRECTORY, file)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_path = os.path.join(path, img)
        #print(img_path)
        label = FILES.index(file)
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        data.append([img, label])

random.shuffle(data)

X=[]
y=[]

for features, label in data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

 #print(" x[3].shape->" , np.shape(X[3])) ->-> gives me  : x[3].shape-> ()

#LBP feature extraction
#__________________________________________________________________________

lbp =[]

for img in X :  
    print( "**** image shape -> ", np.shape(img) #print only first two images 

    lbp.append(feature.local_binary_pattern(img, 8, 3, method="default"))
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe first check what shape has your image - `print( img.shape )`

Comment: @furas thank you I edited the question with the full error message

Comment: @furas it's  ****->  (512, 512)

Comment: i used -> print( "**** image shape -> ", np.shape(X[0])) inside the loop but it's print the shape of the first two image . the third image gives me () . i don't why it's empty

Comment: maybe print `X` to see what gives `()`. As I remeber when `cv` can't read file then It doesn't raise error but it returns `None` and maybe this makes problem. Maybe it can't read some image and you get empty `()`. It may need to add some `if/else` to skip this image. Or maybe you will have to convert this image to different format using external programs.

Comment: I checked `np.shape(None)` gives `()`

Answer (score 1):

**Problem is fixed**

the problem was because None values in the array for some reason it read from empty file so i used if which will not read the empty file

```
for img in os.listdir(path):
        if img!='.DS_Store':
            img_path = os.path.join(path, img)
            print("img path ",  " ", img)
            label = FILES.index(file)
            img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            data.append([img, label])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uo6r.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh2eA.png)

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code with image `RGB` then I get `(512,512,3)` - even if it use `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` in `imread()` - and this can make your problem.

You use wrong value in `imread()`- it has to be `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

---

And value `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` is for function

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems you have another problem.

When `cv2` can't read file then it doesn't raise error but it returns `None` - and later it makes problem. You will have to use `if/else` to skip this image

```
if img is not None:  # can't be `if not img:`
   data.append([img, label])
else:
   print("can't read:", img_path)
```

You may have to also use some external program to convert this image to other format.